# Why does equal dates appear in select when the where statement says they should not match?

Tags: sql, datetime, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am doing some data recon, and want to see if the data in two date fields match. Each of the columns come from a different table, hence I want to check that they are the same. Due to them coming from different table and we dont have a datesync function, to two field are off by miniseconds, perhaps a second here and there. I dont care about the time, I only care if the two field reflect the same date, hence in my where clause I am casting them as dates....... however, this doesn't seem to work as I am still getting all 281 records with or without the

```
and cast(write_off_date as date) <> cast(write_off_action_date as date)
```

My query:

```
select status
    ,write_off_date
    ,write_off_action_date
 from renamed
 where write_off_date is not null or write_off_action_date is not null
    and cast(write_off_date as date) <> cast(write_off_action_date as date)
```

a sample of the data output is :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `OR` condition in parentheses:

```
where (write_off_date is not null or write_off_action_date is not null)
    and cast(write_off_date as date) <> cast(write_off_action_date as date)
```

Rationale - your code is like:

```
condition1 or condition2 and condition3
```

`and` has higher logic precedence than `or`, so this is equivalent to:

```
condition1 or (condition2 and condition3)
```

... which is not what you want.

That said, the whole `where` clause makes little sense. If any of the date is `null`, the inequality condition cannot be fulfilled anyway, so the `not null` conditions are just unecessary.